# Ruby on Rails - Dropdown with Has Many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have four tables in my database. One is users, another is organizations. One user can have many organizations, and one organization can have many users. This relationship is stored in a third table, called user_organizations, with columns user_id and organization_id.

The fourth table is called organization_details, where I store additional, multi-row information about the organization.

What I want to happen is this: when a signed in user wants to add organization details to an org they are linked to through user_organizations, only the organizations they are linked to should appear in the dropdown list.

I am unsure of how to go about this. The system returns information about the signed in user through current_user, for example <%= current_user.first_name %>.

So I'm trying to do something like this:

collection_select(:organization_detail, :organization_id, Organization.where({id: current_user.id...something something about user_organization being here too}), :id, :name_and_state)

What is the best way to approach this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the built in association.  Since User has_many Organizations you can call `current_user.organizations` like this:

```
collection_select(:organization_detail, :organization_id, current_user.organizations, :id, :name_and_state)
```

This assumes you have everything hooked up correctly in the models.

You should also check out the [Rails Guide to associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) if you are new to them.

Comment: Wow, that was way easier than what I was making it to be! Thank you, thank you! I will certainly take a look at the link you've provided. I thought it would be more complicated with the third table.

Answer (score 0):

`current_user.organizations` will do the trick.

your dropdown would look something like this:

```
<ul>
  <%- current_user.organizations.each do |organization| -%>
    <li><%= link_to organization.name, your_path_here %></li>
  <%- end -%>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help; that looks like a good alternative to the dropdown if I would ever go that route. I hate how I make things more complicated than what they need to be in RoR sometimes.